# Where can I find Derrin?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I'm doing the quest "Brave Derrin" at the moment, but I'm having a hard time actually finding the boy. I've explored Ondra's Gift and spoken with some people, but the trail ends at the Salty Mast.

I probably missed something obvious, but I just couldn't find the boy. Where is he?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found him at the following location (he's right about where my party is, the bunch of green circles):

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Had similar problems. Try going into the water during the day and searching around there.